# CoffeeScript/JavaScript how do I error if a parameter is not passed?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, underscore.js, lodash

I thought I was clever by writing code that did this:

```
someFunction = (arg1, arg2, arg3) ->
  if _.some(arguments, (a) -> a is undefined)
    throw new Error "undefined parameter"
```

My intent is that if one of the parameters is undefined, throw an error.  But I just discovered it doesn't always work:  If someone does not pass in a parameter at all, it's not included in the `arguments` array and therefore it doesn't get checked.

Is there an easy way to throw an error if this function is called like `someFunction(1, 2)` or `someFunction(1)` without checking every parameter by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check `arguments.length`.

```
function someFunction(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
    if (arguments.length !== 3) throw new Error('undefined parameter');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `arguments.length`

```
function doSomething(arg1,arg2,arg3){
    if(arguments.length!=3){
          throw new Error("wrong param count");
    }

}
```